# How to get exact width of flexbox by getComputedStyle?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

I have a problem to get exact width of flexbox after rendering contents. 
I am working on a Windows 8 application (mean `ie10` specific).

Here is the code:
[HTML]

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>flexbox test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='viewport'>
            <div class='canvas'>
                <div class="item"> A </div>
                <div class="item"> B </div>
                <div class="item"> C </div>
                <div class="item"> D </div>
                <div class="item"> E </div>
                <div class="item"> F </div>
                <div class="item"> G </div>
                <div class="item"> H </div>
                <div class="item"> I </div>
                <div class="item"> J </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="width: 600px; text-align: left;">
    <div class="outbox"></div>
    <script>tester();</script>
</body>
</html>​
```

[CSS]

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container .viewport {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
}

.container .viewport .canvas{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-flow: row none;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    -ms-flex-item-align: start;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
    position: relative;
}

.container .viewport .canvas .item {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;color: #fff; 
    background-color: black;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[JAVASCRIPT]

```
(function tester(){
    var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
    var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null);
    function addToOutbox(str){
        var outbox = document.querySelector('.outbox');
        outbox.innerText = 'Width: ' + str;
    }
    addToOutbox(style.width);
})();
```

I was expecting width to be something else as there is a scroll bar.
Outer container width is `400px`, middle one is inheriting `width` and `height` with `overflow: auto` and inner most is expandable.
There are eight items in flexbox with width and height `100px` each. So I was expecting the flexbox width abot `900px (i.e. 100px*8 + margin-left and margin-right for each item)` but still getting `400px` only which is parent dimensions. Am I missing something?

Here is the link to JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pdMSR/ [Open with ie10 only]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element really is 400px. The flex items that are positioned past 400px are actually overflowing.

It sounds like what you are really trying to get is the scrollWidth. If you pass in `canvas.scrollWidth` to your `addToOutbox` function you'll get what you are looking for.